# SSRS page break issue always a blank page added at end of report....how to fix it

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008

My report is very simple. I am showing country wise data. I make a group on country code. I want that each country data will show all in single page and other country data will show in next page. so each page will show country wise data. I create only one group on country field. So, I set page break at my group. It is working but the problem is always a blank page added in my report. How to get rid of extra blank page at the end of report?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In report properties, set the "ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace" property to True,by default its False.
I also had this blank page issue but it was solved by setting this property to True.

Answer (score 0):

Try change margins, there is a article about SSRS 2005

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bwelcker/archive/2005/08/19/alien-lanes-_2800_logical-and-physical-pagination-rules_2900_.aspx

Comment: just do not understand what i need to do to remove last blank page after going the the url u mention....plzz discuss briefly if u know.

Comment: I think this is a design issue. Change to page margins to 0 and try again. Btw which version of SSRS you use?

Comment: This issue should be fixed in SSRS 2008. But you can try all page margins to 0. If still same, you can reduce your page borders to fit your report items.

Answer (score 0):

page margin to 0 resolved this for me.  I had blank page in between each page